# Click on Twitter Bookmarks button

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to delete some bookmarks on Twitter using Selenium and Python, but I can't seem to click on the Share / Bookmarks button.
I've tried to use this:

```
username_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id__3xn6pz81l9d"]/div[4]/div/div/div/svg')
username_field.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUGvn.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw on twitter with the browser console, the div next to the svg is clickable but not the svg itself.

You shoud try:

```py
share_bt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id__3xn6pz81l9d"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div')
share_bt.click()
```

You also need to wait the element to be clickable or to be present, usually i go with a wait function:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def WaitFor(method, selector_type, element, timeout):
    try:
        # wait for search results to be fetched
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            method((selector_type, element))
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        driver.quit()
```

and then when i want to click on something:

```py
WaitFor(EC.element_to_be_clickable, By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'CSS_SELECTOR_PATH', 10)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('CSS_SELECTOR_PATH').click()
```

Comment: yeah, weird right! I've just test this and it doesn't work.
I get: 
elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="id__3xn6pz81l9d"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div"}

Comment: Is there a way, maybe with the CSS selector or something else?

Comment: Did you wait the element to be clickable or present before trying selecting it ?

Comment: Yes, tried also Wait and time.sleep but still I can't interact with that element. It doesn't want to click on it. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution on my case:

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    username_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@aria-label, "Share Tweet")]//descendant::*[local-name()="svg"]')))
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@aria-label, "Share Tweet")]//descendant::*[local-name()="svg"]')
    username_field.click()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).